# indent 1cm from left second page onwards

Tags: indentation

How to indent `1cm` from left margin from second page onwards?

I've searched some it says below but using `{description}` instead of center. But I'd like to make my paragraph centered.

```
\begin{center}[1cm]

some text here

\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You want to have your description indented, not the rest of the page content? And why do you want to have (all)? paragraphs centered? This does not look very well, in my point of view

Comment: hello haha err it's required by my faculty for my Final Year Project report.. aiks.. from 2nd page onwards, the margin should be extra 1cm from left.. i guess because i need to bind my report so they leave some space at the side..@ChristianHupfer

Comment: This requires new margins, best to achieved with the `\newgeometry` command from the `geometry` package

Comment: does it affect this \usepackage[top=50mm , bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry} ?? i used it at my main page..

Comment: That does affect all pages then

Comment: can i maintain \usepackage[top=50mm , bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry} for my first page and use \newgeometry after \input mypage ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\newgeometry` can change the page layout parameters, but it does always ship out new page at the place where the `\newgeometry` occurs.

Since the first page seems to be totally different from the rest of the document, the new page is not really an issue here.

Remove the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package to drop the frame drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}

% General setup
\usepackage[top=50mm , bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm,showframe]{geometry}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[4] 
\newgeometry{left=55mm} % new left margin --> will issue a new page
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what's blind text for?? sorry i too noob ..

Comment: It fills the page with dummy text. You don't need for your real document.